# How can I get exact total space of a drive using C language program running on Linux?

Tags: c, linux

How can I get exact total space of a drive using C language program running on Linux? I dont want to use shell script. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`statfs/statfs64`

```
#include <sys/vfs.h>    /* or <sys/statfs.h> */
int statfs(const char *path, struct statfs *buf);
int fstatfs(int fd, struct statfs *buf);
```

From the man page:

> ```
>    The  function  statfs() returns information about a mounted file system.
>    path is the pathname of any file within the mounted file system.
>    buf is a pointer to a statfs structure defined approximately as follows:
>
>        struct statfs {
>           long    f_type;     /* type of file system (see below) */
>           long    f_bsize;    /* optimal transfer block size */
>           long    f_blocks;   /* total data blocks in file system */
>           long    f_bfree;    /* free blocks in fs */
>           long    f_bavail;   /* free blocks avail to non-superuser */
>           long    f_files;    /* total file nodes in file system */
>           long    f_ffree;    /* free file nodes in fs */
>           fsid_t  f_fsid;     /* file system id */
>           long    f_namelen;  /* maximum length of filenames */
>        };
> ```

You can use it like this:

```
struct statfs buf;
statfs("/", &buf);
```